# CSS Shrink label & td cell to accommodate text

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox list that I need to make horizontal. The checkboxes and labels are all appearing on the same row but the spacing between them is very far apart, is there a way to shrink each cell to be only as large as the checkbox and label inside of it? JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrcZ2/

```
<table id="form_3D7" class="scfCheckBoxList">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="form_3D7" type="checkbox" value="One" name="form_3D7">
        <label for="form_3D7">One</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="form_3D8" type="checkbox" value="Two" name="form_3D8">
        <label for="form_387">Two</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="form_3D9" type="checkbox" value="Three" name="form_3D9">
        <label for="form_3D9">Three</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.scfCheckBoxList {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

tbody {
   display: table-row-group;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
   display: table-row;
   vertical-align: inherit;
}

.scfCheckBoxList td {
   vertical-align: top;
}

.scfCheckBoxList input {
   float: left;
   width: 30px;
}

.scfCheckBoxList label {
   clear: none;
   font-weight: normal;
   padding: 0;
   width: 68%;
}

.scfForm input {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've inherited this code and trying to shrink the table cells to only be as large as the text inside of them. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your table has 100% width.

Comment: Given that you describe it as a list, why are you using a `table`, and not a `ul` or `ol`?

Comment: I'm working under a CMS and this is just the code it's generated

Comment: you're right, I fixed that, I copy and pasted, it's not like that in my code.

Comment: So, 100% width, do you need that? If not, remove it. If so, you can use colspan to merge those cells together while keeping the width: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yrcZ2/1/

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed the table `width` from `100%` to `auto`